# Reshaping data in R for multiple value types

Tags: r

This is a relatively simple question but I'm having some issues (thank you in advance!). My data looks like this (minimal working example):

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c("A","A","A"),
  org = c("USA","CHN","CHN"),
  partner = c("USA","USA","MEX")
)

> df
  ID org partner
1  A USA     USA
2  A CHN     USA
3  A CHN     MEX
```

However, I want it to look like this:

```
df_wide <- data.frame(
  ID = c("A"),
  org1 = c("USA"),
  org2 = c("CHN"),
  partner1 = c("USA"),
  partner2 = c("MEX")
)

> df_wide
  ID org1 org2 partner1 partner2
1  A  USA  CHN      USA      MEX
```

Note: the data has many rows and IDs. Each ID is associated with an unknown number of origin countries and an unknown number of partner countries. So, for example, I *don't* want to impose that there are max 2 origin countries per ID.

Additionally, how can I make the data look like this?

```
df_wide2 <- data.frame(
  ID = c("A")
)
df_wide2$org = list(c("USA","CHN"))
df_wide2$partner = list(c("USA","MEX"))

> df_wide2
  ID      org  partner
1  A USA, CHN USA, MEX
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After grouping by 'ID', we can get the `unique` elements and `paste`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ toString(unique(.)))
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#   ID    org      partner 
#  <fct> <chr>    <chr>   
#1 A     USA, CHN USA, MEX
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm having trouble testing this because it's taking so long to run. Do you know what the issue here is? My data has 2.5 million observations.

Comment: @H.Z Can you  try `library(data.table);setDT(df)[,  lapply(.SD, function(x) toString(unique(x))), by = ID]` on a fresh R sessiion